# Generating ASP POST secure variables

Tags: php, parsing, curl

I want to parse search result of one site builded on ASP with using PHP CURL. No problems with DOM but there is problem with POST variables. And i don't know how to generate it in my php script.

ASP generates 6 variables with __ prefix.

```
__EVENTTARGET
__EVENTARGUMENT (has Value like base 64 encoded)
__LASTFOCUS
__VIEWSTATE (has Value)
__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED
__EVENTVALIDATION (has Value like base 64 encoded)
```

And i tried to copy POST data from my browser with help of httpfox and with this data script works half of hour:

```
...
define('POSTVARS', '__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=1wI2MmTCR4DM7poU...
...
url_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    ,POSTVARS);
...
```

How to generate __EVENTARGUMENT, __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION?

PS. Parsing site is http://nakolesah.ru/. I parse result of form. Id of form submit button is "ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_btnSearchWheels". Result page is: http://nakolesah.ru/wheels/podbor/porazmeru.aspx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot generate those values. They are generated by ASP.NET, encrypted with the server machine keys and have a certain validity. The only way to make this work is to first send a GET request to the main page, scrape the HTML, get the values of those hidden fields and after that send the POST request using the values you have read.

Comment: aham, Thanx, I'll try to do that.